# EntityFramework classes gets deleted after update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I changed my database model so that one of the tables foreign key accepted null values.
Afterwards I went to my `.edmx` file and did the "Update model from database..." and after saving it all my class files representing the tables got deleted automatically.

If I revert my changes in the database and resave my `.edmx`, the classes will reappear. But I really want this foreign key to be able to accept nulls. What could be causing this?

Comment: When you update the model it deletes everything?

Comment: Are you using this in conjunction with the T4 templates? If so, you can right click on the T4 files and re-run the templates that will create the POCO .cs class files for each table. Or in the worst case just delete the EDMX and re-create it.

Comment: Jonesy: Yes, all the model classes.

Comment: Code Monkey: I'm sorry but I don't really know what T4 templates are

Comment: After you update your edmx and click save, stay with the edmx opened and check error window and warning window. Do you see any error/warning related to the edmx file ?

Comment: Is it that the classes completely disappear? or have you defined custom stuff in partial classes and it's those that disappear?

Comment: I've been experiencing this issue from time to time after making database changes.  I haven't noticed a pattern to explain why it happens sometimes.  I have to make sure the one other team member isn't affected, so I have to lose my work, download the TFS server version, and start over.  This happens only to me, never the other team member.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework 6.1.3.  It would be marvelous if anybody could ever explain what's going on and how I can prevent the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve it by recreating the edmx model but yes, there was some error in the error list. They were pointing to some contraints not working anymore

Answer (score 12):

For anyone else who may have this issue, and who may not want to have to recreate their EDMX:

I had a similar issue that occurred repeatedly, which I've been able to fix by filtering the Error List by "Build Only".

Once I'd done this, I found a number of errors regarding Multiplicity conflicts, which I was able to solve by navigating to **Associations** under the **Model Browser** and changing the End1 and End2 Multiplicity values (where applicable).

In my case, removing the ability for a FK column to be null (in the DB) resulted in the Entity Designer not being able to maintain a 1..1 multiplicity. Switching it to 0..1 fixed the problem.