# Context.cs is empty after updating from database, .edmx file generates it empty

Tags: entity-framework

I have an .edmx diagram, EF 6, sometimes when I update from database it just generates the Context.cs file empty and no class at all!
We work in different teams so not always I can know exaclty what tables were updated.

Is there any error log I can use to sort this out? How can I debug and fix this issue when EF is in a bad mood?

Comment: Sorry about the fluff :)

Comment: Answers to this question may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127633/why-does-visual-studio-delete-my-classes-when-i-update-entity-framework-model/36849153#36849153

Answer (score 18):

Ok I found a way around it.

You have to delete on the diagram one by one and save each time you delete an entity.
When the buggy entity is discarded it will generate the classes again.
At this moment you Update From Database and it updates everything nicely.

-- Update 10/12/20 --

Thanks to Dimitar that pointed out it could be confusing the deleting part: you don't need to delete all entities, just the problematic one (if you know which one it is).
The approach to delete entities one by one is to find the problematic one.

Comment: Upvoted and fixed my issue, just to prevent confusing someone, if they know which table/view is causing the issue, just delete it straightway, no need to delete the others. In my case, it was the fact that I manually added a navigation & association property to a mapped entity.

Comment: Same here...I was getting the following error which pointed the way.
Removed the referenced table, then put it back and VS is happy again (as am I):

Running transformation: Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Stop_Detail' in relationship 'FK_Stop_Event_To_Stop_Detail'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.